# Change rights of `/etc/passwd` in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, podman, passwd

I am building a Podman image for Openshift, and have an issue with permissions.

Following [this guide](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/jupyter-on-openshift-part-6-running-as-an-assigned-user-id), and because Openshift assigns a random UID and a GID "0" when running containers, I try to `chmod` the `/etc/passwd` to be writable by its group and add my Openshift user in it at runtime; but it seems that I can't always `chmod` that `/etc/passwd` file.

Minimal Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

USER root

RUN ls -l /etc/passwd
RUN chmod g+w /etc/passwd
RUN ls -l /etc/passwd
```

When building (`sudo podman build . -t test-image`), I see the correct rights on `/etc/passwd`:

```
STEP 1: FROM ubuntu:20.04
STEP 2: USER root
--> Using cache 2cb48e4f8eed907e057017011e20ddc47ec8f152bb7afe34ecf6be23413cd08b
STEP 3: RUN ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 926 Sep 21 16:48 /etc/passwd
     ^
     ^
     ^
79f60398d64ece1b413fd904681ad5fd0725bae4b283abce7b7a9ea017d4ebe7
STEP 4: RUN chmod g+w /etc/passwd
6ed13401ab693dbc362ec90b9c3767c1cd2244074ca4e92bd1b31b72b3e80868
STEP 5: RUN ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 926 Sep 21 16:48 /etc/passwd
     ^
     ^
     ^
STEP 6: COMMIT test
d667b2c05818b5af3c9db85a5e7179c8e7b1c21281e31c34a871e97268716f39
```

When I run my container with `root` user, no issue:

```
[user@server]$ sudo podman run -it test-image /bin/bash
root@295ab7b72a4d:/# ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 926 Sep 21 16:48 /etc/passwd
     ^
     ^
     ^
```

But when I run with a random user, `/etc/passwd` rights aren't changed anymore...

```
[user@server]$ sudo podman run -it -u 1000701200:0 test-image /bin/bash
1000701200@a63d9bf9f53a:/$ ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 977 Oct 19 08:51 /etc/passwd
     ^
     ^
     ^
```

Why do the rights on `/etc/passwd` depend on the user who run the container?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: This is not the case with a random file I create, it works as expected. So there is something special about the `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: Just tried that and with my setup the file has group write permissions - I use 3.4.0

Comment: Podman seems to automatically add the user to the /etc/passwd - interesting

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use version 1.4.4... Might be the issue. In the meantime I found [this](https://access.redhat.com/articles/4859371) which says it's a bad practice and that the recommended way would be to use `nss_wrapper`... So I'll give it a try

Comment: Hi, no update. I've seen that the Git associated with the guide I initially used is deprecated, so I guess it's not the best practice anymore... But I didn't have time to investigate further

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with `podman version 3.4.1` neither executing podman throught sudo nor without sudo.

Comment: Indeed podman version was the issue it seems - it works fine after updating... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The podman version was at cause - updating to 3.x version solved the issue.